# obtener las 3 primeras palabras de una frase en PHP

Tags: php

Tengo una duda sobre como obtener las 2 o 3 primeras palabras de una frase. Por ejemplo:

Ejemplo_1:

```
$text_1 = "Chaleco azul con tejido algodón";
Resultado=> Chaleco azul
```

Ejemplo_2:

```
$text_2 = "Lampara de lectura para la cama";
Resultado=> Lampara de lectura
```

Ejemplo_3:

```
$text_3 = "Suave oso de peluche de color morado";
Resultado=> Suave oso peluche
```

Si os fijáis a veces puede coger el "DE", como en el ejemplo 2, en cambio en el ejemplo 3 no coge el "DE". No se como también se pueda discriminar la letras "DE".

**Digo yo...** Si la siguiente palabra es superior a 4 caracteres, añádela de lo contrario no suprime el resto de palabras sobrantes...

*Gracias de Antemano*

---

Perdonarme, por haberme explicado tan mal. Os detallo mejor la idea y con mas ejemplos, y gracias por las rapidas respuestas. ;)

La idea es obtener siempre las 3 primeras palabras, salvo cuando en la 3º Posición se encuentre un "DE". En cuyo caso incluiríamos la palabra que ocupa la 4º posición.

```
$Ejemplo_1= "zapatillas de fútbol para correr";

Resultado_1=> zapatillas de fútbol
```

Como podéis observar en el Resultado_1, rescatamos siempre las 3 primeras palabras. En este caso el "DE" no acaba en la 3ºposición, por tanto el resultado estaría OK.

```
$Ejemplo_2= "15 metros de lona para el restaurante";

Resultado_2: 15 metros de lona
```

En el Resultado_2, si os fijáis en la 3º Posición acaba con un "DE", por tanto se cumple el requisito que mencione arriba. Por tanto únicamente cogeremos la próxima palabra que esta en la 4º Posición.

```
$Ejemplo_3= "Tarjeta memoria kodak 15 fotografías HD";

Resultado_3: Tarjeta memoria kodak
```

En el Resultado_3, únicamente coge las 3 palabras, ya que no contiene ningún "DE".

Comment: Hola Fumatamax. Qué usas actualmente para crear los `resultado` de los textos?  O es solo el resultado que esperas conseguir? Si aun no lo has hecho has de investigar e intentarlo y si tienes problemas concretos o errores, preguntar aqui siguiendo [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo

Comment: @Fumatamax no entiendo cuáles son las reglas. ¿Siempre depende de la palabra `de` (en la 2da posición, obtener 3; en la 3ra, ignorar y obtener la 4ta)? ¿O sólo con palabras de 4 caracteres, y por qué tomaría `oso`? ¿O de qué depende? Pensá que no tenemos una bola de cristal para adivinar lo que estás haciendo...Fijate si esto te sirve: http://rextester.com/VVG15896

Comment: @Fumatamax, no añadas nueva información en las respuestas. En lugar de eso, dale a [edit] tu pregunta.

Comment: @Fumatamax con tu nueva edición, tu primer ejemplo no tiene sentido, ¿no sería `Chaleco azul con`? ¿O por qué toma `Suave oso peluche` en vez de `Suave oso de peluche`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

He hecho un método algo genérico para lo que quieres:

```
function cortarFrase($frase, $maxPalabras = 3, $noTerminales = ["de"]) {
  $palabras = explode(" ", $frase);
  $numPalabras = count($palabras);
  if ($numPalabras > $maxPalabras) {
     $offset = $maxPalabras - 1;
     while (in_array($palabras[$offset], $noTerminales) && $offset < $numPalabras) { $offset++; }
     return implode(" ", array_slice($palabras, 0, $offset + 1));
  }
  return $frase;
}
```

Este método admite hasta tres parámetros:

- $frase: la frase a recortar
- $maxPalabras: el número de palabras con las que quieres quedarte. Parámetro opcional con valor inicial 3.
- $noTerminales: una lista de las palabras con las que no debe terminar el recorte. Parámetro opcional con valor inicial ["de"]

Entonces lo que hace es romper la cadena y transformarla en un array (con `explode`). Si la cadena tiene 3 palabras o menos, se devuelve la cadena sin cambios; si tiene más de 3 palabras, entonces comprobar que la última palabra no está en la lista de palabras no permitidas como terminales (añadiendo una palabra más a la cadena si lo está).

---

Por ejemplo, usando esa función en el siguiente código:

```
<?php

$frase1 = "zapatillas de fútbol para correr";
$frase2 = "15 metros de lona para el restaurante";
$frase3 = "Tarjeta memoria kodak 15 fotografías HD";

function cortarFrase($frase, $maxPalabras = 3, $noTerminales = ["de"]) {
    $palabras = explode(" ", $frase);
    $numPalabras = count($palabras);
    if ($numPalabras > $maxPalabras) {
        $offset = $maxPalabras - 1;
        while (in_array($palabras[$offset], $noTerminales) && $offset < $numPalabras) { $offset++; }
        return implode(" ", array_slice($palabras, 0, $offset+1));
    }
    return $frase;
}


echo cortarFrase($frase1) . "\n";
echo cortarFrase($frase2) . "\n";
echo cortarFrase($frase3) . "\n";
// quedarse con 4 palabras en lugar de 3
echo cortarFrase($frase1, 4) . "\n";
// quedarse con 3 palabras, pero no puede terminar en "de" o "lona"
echo cortarFrase($frase2, 3, ["de", "lona"]) . "\n";
```

obtendrá como resultado:

> zapatillas de fútbol
>   15 metros de lona
>   Tarjeta memoria kodak
>   zapatillas de fútbol para
>   15 metros de lona para

Answer (score 3):

> obtener siempre las 3 primeras palabras, salvo cuando en la 3º Posición se encuentre un `DE`. En cuyo caso incluiríamos la palabra que ocupa la 4º posición.

Podemos usar el regex

```
/^\W*(?:\w+\W+){2}(?:de\W+)?\w+/iu
```

que coincide con las 2 primeras palabras `^\W*(?:\w+\W+){2}`, opcionalmente `(?:de\W+)?` y la última palabra `\w+`.

Código:

```
if (preg_match( '/^\W*(?:\w+\W+){2}(?:de\W+)?\w+/iu', $texto, $match)) {
    $resultado = $match[0];
}
```

---

Demo:

```
$pruebas = [
    "Chaleco azul con tejido algodón",
    "Lampara de lectura para la cama",
    "Suave oso de peluche de color morado",
    "zapatillas de fútbol para correr",
    "15 metros de lona para el restaurante",
    "Tarjeta memoria kodak 15 fotografías HD"
];

foreach ($pruebas as &$texto) {
    if (preg_match( '/^\W*(?:\w+\W+){2}(?:de\W+)?\w+/iu', $texto, $match)) {
        $resultado =  $match[0];

        //imprimimos
        echo $texto . "\t\t=>\t" . $resultado . "\n";
    }
}
```

Resultado:

```
Chaleco azul con tejido algodón         =>  Chaleco azul con
Lampara de lectura para la cama         =>  Lampara de lectura
Suave oso de peluche de color morado    =>  Suave oso de peluche
zapatillas de fútbol para correr        =>  zapatillas de fútbol
15 metros de lona para el restaurante   =>  15 metros de lona
Tarjeta memoria kodak 15 fotografías HD =>  Tarjeta memoria kodak
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar la función explode de PHP de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
    $texto = "Chaleco azul con tejido algodón";
    $palabras = explode(" ", $texto);
?>
```

De esta forma tienes un array en $palabras que contiene las palabras de la frase, luego puedes usar in_array para buscar las que quieres. Para coger las 3 primeras sería:

```
<?php
    if(count($palabras) >= 3)
        for($i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++)
            echo $palabra[$i];
?>
```

Pero por lo que cuentas, creo que lo que quieres es analizar la frase y quedarte con la parte del sujeto. En cuyo caso, es demasiado complejo para responderlo aquí. Puede que con técnicas de IA, redes neuronales y tal...

Answer (score 2):

Otra posibilidad sería usar expresiones regulares. La idea sería obtener la subcadena compuesta por `palabra1-espacio-palabra2-espacio-palabra3`, donde `palabra3` no puede ser "de", y si es "de", entonces debe tomarse el siguiente espacio y la siguiente palabra.

La expresión regular para eso sería:

> Nota: con esta expresión regular se estarían buscando no sólo espacios en blanco sino cualquier tipo de separador (también valdrían tabuladores por ejemplo).

```
/^((?:\S+\s+){2}((de\s\S+)|(\S+))).*/
```

Que hace lo descrito arriba: toma las dos primeras palabras (`(?:\S+\s+){2}`) y una de estas dos: "de" seguido de un separador y de otra palabra (`(de\s\S+)`), o cualquier otra palabra (`(\S+)`) hasta el siguiente separador.

Entonces en PHP podrías correr esa expresión regular y devolver la subcadena que cumpla con ella y, si no se encuentra ninguna, devolver la cadena completa (porque significaría que tiene menos de 3 palabras). El código sería algo así:

```
<?php

$frase1 = "zapatillas de fútbol para correr";
$frase2 = "15 metros de lona para el restaurante";
$frase3 = "Tarjeta memoria kodak 15 fotografías HD";
$frase4 = "Hola Caracola";

function cortarFrase($frase) {

    preg_match('/^((?:\S+\s+){2}((de\s\S+)|(\S+))).*/', $frase, $matches);
    if (isset($matches[1])) { return $matches[1]; }

    return $frase;
}

echo cortarFrase($frase1) . "\n";
echo cortarFrase($frase2) . "\n";
echo cortarFrase($frase3) . "\n";
echo cortarFrase($frase4) . "\n";
```

Y el resultado que se obtiene sería éste:

> zapatillas de fútbol
>   15 metros de lona
>   Tarjeta memoria kodak
>   Hola Caracola

Comment: @Mariano la estaba leyendo ahora mismo. Cuando publiqué mi respuesta estuve a punto de mandarte un mensaje

Answer (score 0):

Usa `<?php echo $ejemplo1= substr($ejemplo1, 0, 100); ?>` cambiando el valor final por las letras a filtrar.