# Generador de frases célebres

Tags: php

Buen día. Estoy imaginando una herramienta para la generación (y difusión) de frases célebres de autores conocidos.

En otra pregunta Álvaro Montoro compartió un script muy interesante que copio y modifico a continuación para plantear mi pregunta. https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/138802/80133

```
function cortarFrase($texto, $maxPalabras = 20, $noTerminales = ["de"]) {
  $frase = explode(" ", $texto);
  $numPalabras = count($frase);
  if ($numPalabras > $maxPalabras) {
     $offset = $maxPalabras - 1;
     while (in_array($frase[$offset], $noTerminales) && $offset < $numPalabras) { $offset++; }
     return implode(" ", array_slice($frase, 0, $offset + 1));
  }
  return $texto;
} echo cortarFrase($texto, 20);
```

admite hasta tres parámetros:

```
$texto: el texto a recortar
$maxPalabras: el número de palabras que contendrá la frase.
$noTerminales: una lista de las palabras con las que no debe terminar el recorte. Parámetro opcional con valor inicial ["de"]
```

Ahora bien, mi cuestionamiento va sobre la variable $texto a la que se le aplica el explode para la generación de frases. En mi caso la variable $texto contiene textos largos, cuentos, poemas, etc., los cuales se almacenan en una columna de base de datos. Con una consulta a la base de datos se pueden escoger múltiples textos de la base de datos para la generación de frases distintas, pero **cómo hacer para que al pasarle el explode al texto de una entrada se generen frases aleatorias iniciando en cualquier punto del texto y no partiendo del inicio del texto como hace**, por lo que siempre genera la misma frase. No entiendo bien cómo hacerlo

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Según veo, en tu caso no te hace falta complicarte así. La función en la que quieres basarte tiene como objetivo el recibir una frase y devolver la frase en múltiples trozos de una longitud determinada.

En tu caso, vas a tener frases independientes y acotadas, vas a saber perfectamente donde empieza y donde termina una frase porque cada una de ellas va a estar en un registro de la **DB**.

Partiendo de esa base propongo esta solución:

```
$frases = ['Todos somos aficionados. La vida es tan corta que no da para más',
          'Si no sueltas el pasado, ¿con qué mano agarras el futuro?',
          'No cambies lo que más quieres en la vida por lo que más quieres en el momento, porque los momentos pasan y la vida sigue.'
          , 'Cuando no sepas dónde ir, sigue el perfume de un sueño.'];

print_r(muestra_frases($frases, 2));

/****************************************************************  
$frases = Array con las frases recuperadas de la Base de Datos
$numero = Número de frases de la lista que quiero mostrar  
*****************************************************************/   
function muestra_frases($frases, $numero) {
    $respuesta = array();

    if ($numero > count($frases)) {
        array_push($respuesta, 'El número de frases a mostrar excede la cantidad de frases recibida');
    }
    else {
        shuffle ($frases);

        for ($i = 0; $i < $numero; $i++) {
            array_push ($respuesta, $frases[$i]);
        }
    }

    return $respuesta;
}
```

La función recibe un `array` con las frases recuperadas de la **DB**, lo desordena con la función `shuffle()` (para coger frases aleatoriamente) y te devuelve un `array` con el número de frases de la lista que le has pasado como parámetro.

Le añadí también un control para que si el número de frases solicitado excede el número de frases recibido que devuelva un mensaje de error.

**SOLUCIÓN 2**

Basándome en el código de la función de la que partes, le he añadido un parámetro más que sea el número de palabra por el que empieza. De esa manera no siempre comenzarías por el principio de la cadena (pudiendo pasarle un número aleatorio, por ejemplo).

```
$frase_mia = 'En un lugar de la Mancha, de cuyo nombre no quiero acordarme, no ha mucho tiempo que vivía un hidalgo de los de lanza en astillero, adarga antigua, rocín flaco y galgo corredor.';

echo '<p>' . cortarFrase($frase_mia, 15, 6) . '</p>';

function cortarFrase($texto, $maxPalabras = 20, $palabra_inicio = 0, $noTerminales = ["de"]) {
  $frase = explode(" ", $texto);
  $numPalabras = count($frase);
  if ($numPalabras > $maxPalabras) {
     $offset = $maxPalabras - 1;
     while (in_array($frase[$offset], $noTerminales) && $offset < $numPalabras) { 
         $offset++; 
     }
     return implode(" ", array_slice($frase, $palabra_inicio, $offset + 1));
  }
  return $texto;
}
```

Comment: ok. Gracias, pero no era mi pregunta. Tu función parte de que una matriz de frases y las elige aleatoriamente, pero no es eso lo que queremos. La idea es que la función genere frases cortas a partir de textos largos, para eso hay que pasarle un explode al $texto. El problema con la función que puse arriba es que siempre genera la misma frase partiendo del inicio del texto y no iniciando en cualquier punto del texto.

Comment: No comprendo muy bien. Lo que dices te puede generar frases que no contengan significado por estar cortadas donde no deben. Ejemplo: **Frase:** En un lugar de la Mancha, de cuyo nombre no quiero acordarme, no ha mucho tiempo que vivía un hidalgo de los de lanza en astillero, adarga antigua, rocín flaco y galgo corredor. **Resultado:**  tiempo que vivía un hidalgo de los de lanza en astillero. ¿Es eso lo que necesitas?

Comment: Exactamente eso es lo que necesito

Comment: Actualicé mi respuesta para darte una segunda solución que parte del código del compañero @Alvaro Montoro

Comment: Gracias. Ya la probé y funciona. Aunque como decías antes pueden quedar frases incoherentes, por lo que he estado pensando que se puede complejizar $palabra_inicio para que reconozca algún expresión regular, por ejemplo, que inicie en una letra mayúscula o solo en párrafos, tal vez con preg_split. en lugar de un rand(1,1000). También que reconozca caracteres en lugar de palabras con substr. Sigo intentando!!